# Excel VBA Pass Cell Array into Function

Tags: arrays, vba, function, excel

I'm trying to write a simple VBA Function like this:

```
Public Function ReturnMMult(Arr1() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant) As Variant

    ReturnMMult = WorksheetFunction.MMult(Arr1,Arr2)

End Function
```

But it always gives me #VALUE! I've tried changing the Arr's to Ranges, but that doesn't work either. I basically want to be able to write functions that can take ranges like $A1:$A10 or something like that. Looked in a lot of places, and can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want a function that replicates a worksheet function?

Comment: If I can solve this, I can solve my real problem. Just need to know how to do this in general.

Comment: It looks like MMult returns an array, try something like Public Function ReturnMMult(a As Excel.Range, b As Excel.Range) As Variant()

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what's your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
Public Function M(a As Excel.Range, b As Excel.Range) As Variant()
    Dim a1() As Variant
    Dim a2() As Variant
    a1 = a.value
    a2 = b.value
    M = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(a1, a2)
End Function
```

Comment: You will need to add some checks that the columns in a is equal to the rows in b, and also, this error's, so you'll need to error trap to be safe.  And also scott's post :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring them in as ranges then shift them to arrays:

```
Public Function ReturnMMult(Arr1rng As Range, Arr2rng As Range) As Variant
Dim Arr1() As Variant: Arr1 = Arr1rng.Value
Dim Arr2() As Variant: Arr2 = Arr2rng.Value
ReturnMMult = WorksheetFunction.MMult(Arr1, Arr2)

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of usage of MMult worksheet function. Please adopt it to your situation.

```
Sub test() 

    Dim xArray As Variant, yArray As Variant, zArray As Variant 
    Dim Fn As Object 
    Set Fn = Application.WorksheetFunction 

    xArray = Range("A1:B2").Value 
    yArray = Range("D1:E2").Value 
    zArray = Fn.MMult(xArray, yArray) 

    ActiveCell.Resize(2, 2).Value = zArray 

End Sub
```

MMult returns the #VALUE! error when:
Any cells are empty or contain text.
The number of columns in array1 is different from the number of rows in array2.
The size of the resulting array is equal to or greater than a total of 5,461 cells. Reference [WorksheetFunction.MMult method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.mmult.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: I'm trying to do this with the arrays as parameters.